# preventDefault() not working when css icon is applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, font-awesome

Wondering if anybody has experienced this. I am trying to `e.preventDefault()`every time the tooltip is clicked. When it is clicked, it loads an iframe with a youtube video. However, `preventDefault()` does nothing in this case. I have used a javascript debugger and it is finding the `spanClick()` function.

Here is the strange thing that happens. When I remove 'fa' from the class section, the `preventDefault()` works.
So when `class="fa-question-circle right has-tip tip-left"`, the preventDefault works and the iframe video will load. However, the Font Awesome question mark icon will not load, obviously because 'fa' is missing from the class.

Is there a known issue with Font Awesome icon bypassing preventDefault, or creating another 'click' event that happens either before or after `spanClick()`happens?

Thanks in advance. Below is the code that is supposed to interact with each other.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/INSERTYTLINK"><span data-width="250px" data-tooltip="" class="fa fa-question-circle right has-tip tip-left" onclick="spanClick()" title="Watch the video for more information"></span></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function spanClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:** When I inspected the element on firefox, I noticed that this event is hooked up when the click happens. Is there anything here I can alter or prevent from within my markup?

```
function() {
  if ($(this).parents('.sfSubscribe').length) {
    $(this).parents('.sfSubscribe').find('input:submit').click();
  } else if ($(this).parents('.sfsearchBox').length) {
    console.log('asd');
    $(this).parents('.sfsearchBox').find('input:submit').trigger('click');
  } else {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because the onclick handler is attached to the span element, which doesn't redirect, the anchor does, and it's the anchors click that has to be prevented, not the the click on the span, which bubbles regardless of wether or not it's prevented

You also need to add the event as an argument

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/INSERTYTLINK" onclick="spanClick(event)"><span data-width="250px" data-tooltip="" class="fa fa-question-circle right has-tip tip-left" title="Watch the video for more information"></span></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function spanClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/w9tbx840/)

One could also stop the event bubbling with `e.stopPropagation` on the span

Comment: well that makes sense. however, I tried that and nothing changed. the postback still happened, I've also tried e.stopPropogation() and also passing the event into spanClick.

Comment: Like I've mentioned in the question, when I remove the 'fa' class from the span class, the preventDefault() works. That's the only thing that I've altered in the code that gets the desired results. However, now I have no question mark icon..

Comment: From the updated code, you have javascript code that submits a form, if the issue is that the form is submitted, preventing the default behaviour of the anchor won't help, you have to delete the line of code that submits the form.

Comment: I've attempted to comment out that code to see if that would change anything. I'll update in a bit. My issues might stem from Sitefinity, the cms that we are using, as opposed to our code...

Comment: hey so I'm not sure that code should be deleted as it is contained in 'main.js' which handles a bunch of sitefinity functions..

Comment: I can't help you with that, all I'm saying is that if the function you've posted runs when clicking the anchor, the form submits and the page reloads, and preventing default or doing anything else doesn't change that as the click handler is added in javascript.

Comment: yeah I noticed that when I inspect element, this over javascript click event happens before spanClick(event) is called. thanks for your help regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You are also calling the event as `onclick='spanClick()'` but not passing an event object, like `onclick='spanClick(event)'`  `e` is `undefined` unless you do that.  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/fj00bpev/

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to provide event as parameter while calling the function 
spanClick

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/1jc9cfdd/

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/INSERTYTLINK">
    <span data-width="250px" data-tooltip="" class="fa fa-question-circle right has-tip tip-left" onclick="spanClick(event)" title="Watch the video for more information">hello
    </span>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function spanClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Comment: that didn't work. tried that as well. I'm about to update my question with some new details.